# JSON: Adding missing quotes and commas automatically in WebStorm

Tags: json, validation, webstorm, autoformatting, autoformat

I get from a service json-like-data with several hundred different structures:

```
{
    car112: {
        n: Audi
        type: A4 20 TDI ultra daylight
        sd: 01.07.2016
        p: 34216
        st: false
    }
    car113: {
        n: BMW
        type: not known
        st: true
    }
}
```

and want to get quotes and commas automatically added in WebStorm, so that I have a valid JSON file afterwards:

```
{
    "car112": {
        "n": "Audi",
        "type": "A4 2,0 TDI ultra daylight",
        "sd": "01.07.2016",
        "p": 34216,
        "st": false
    },
    "car113": {
        "n": "BMW",
        "type": "not known",
        "st": true
    }
}
```

How could I do that easily?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is 'Wrap with double quotes' quickfix available on Alt+Enter: `Alt+Enter`, `Right`, `Fix all 'Compliance with JSON standard problems in file`. But unfortunately it doesn't correctly work for values with words separated with white spaces/dots ([WEB-22240](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22240)). And it doesn't allow adding missing commas. So it seems that your only option is using Find/Replace with regexp